# how to add logging function in sending and receiving action in akka

Tags: scala, akka

Now, I am asked to add logging function in akka's actor.

When a message is received, before it is handled, this message should be written into log.
And before a message is sent out, this message should be logged first.

I think I should override the `receive` and `send` functions in Actor. Suppose I create a trait `actorlog` which extends `Actor`. And class `myActor` extends `actorlog`. But in `myActor`, I need to override `receive` function (it seems it causes problems here). So I am confused what I should do.

PS. I know akka provides logging. But now I need implement this function by myself.

Comment: Does [Akka documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.3/scala/logging.html) have no information that can help you? You don't need to override `receive` just for logging purposes, though it has its uses in other scenarios.

Comment: @S.R.I, I know that. But now I need do it by myself. It is my course project...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Besides the other answers here, another approach is to use `orElse` to prepend a partial function to your `receive`.  In that partial function, put the logging in `isDefinedAt` so it gets called on every message.

For example:

```
trait ReceiveLogger {
  this: Actor with ActorLogging =>

  def logMessage: Receive = new Receive {
    def isDefinedAt(x: Any) = {
      log.debug(s"Got a $x")
      false
    }
    def apply(x: Any) = throw new UnsupportedOperationException  
  }
}  

class MyActor extends Actor with ActorLogging with ReceiveLogger {
  def receive: Receive = logMessage orElse {
     case ...
  }
}
```

Using `orElse` is a general approach for composing `receive` behavior.  In most cases I am composing things like this:

```
def otherBehavior: Receive = {
  case OtherMessage => ...
}

class MyActor extends Actor {
  def receive = otherBehavior orElse {
    case ...
  }
}
```

A good example of the stackable traits approach can be seen in this presentation: http://www.slideshare.net/EvanChan2/akka-inproductionpnw-scala2013

Answer (score 25):

There is a utility to get logging of the received messages in Akka. It's briefly mentioned [in the logging documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/logging.html). Basically you wrap your receive function in it like this:

```
def receive = LoggingReceive {
                // your normal receive here
              }
```

And then you enable it in your config with:

```
akka.actor.debug.receive=on
```

The information will be logged at debug level.

Answer (score 2):

1. use stackable modificator `abstract override` for stackable call of `receive` method.
2. use new feature of Akka: event-sourced actor system (docs [here](https://github.com/eligosource/eventsourced)).