# How to `andThen` Akka `Receive`s?

Tags: scala, akka

I have the following:

```
def become(r: ListMap[String, Receive]) {
  val undefined: PartialFunction[Any, Unit] = Map.empty

  val receive = r.foldLeft(undefined) { (accum: Receive, rhs: Pair[String, Receive]) =>
    accum orElse rhs._2
  }

  val echo: Receive = {
    case message => println(s"*************************************************** ${sender}: processing ${message}")
  }

  context.become(echo andThen receive)
}
```

`receive` by itself works fine, but when `echo andThen receive` is used, the system spits out a bunch of:

```
scala.MatchError: () (of class scala.runtime.BoxedUnit)
    at scala.PartialFunction$$anon$1.apply(PartialFunction.scala:248)
    at scala.PartialFunction$$anon$1.apply(PartialFunction.scala:246)
    at kvstore.Replica$$anonfun$secondary$1.applyOrElse(Replica.scala:234)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction$mcVL$sp.apply$mcVL$sp(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction$mcVL$sp.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction$mcVL$sp.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:25)
    at kvstore.Replica$$anonfun$primary$1.applyOrElse(Replica.scala:148)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.apply(PartialFunction.scala:162)
    at scala.PartialFunction$class.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:118)
    at scala.collection.AbstractMap.applyOrElse(Map.scala:58)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.apply(PartialFunction.scala:162)
    at scala.PartialFunction$AndThen.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:185)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:498)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:456)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:237)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:219)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:386)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

The stacktrace points to:

```
def secondary(
                // expected sequence id
                expectedSeq: Long,
                // a map from sequence id to replication requester
                replicationRequester: Map[Long, ActorRef],
                // a map from key to triple of sequence id, persistence repeat, and persistence timeout
                persistenceSchedulers: Map[String, Triple[Long, Cancellable, Cancellable]]): Receive = {
```

and:

```
def primary(
              // a map from secondary replicas to replicators
              replicators: Map[ActorRef, ActorRef],
              // a map from pair of key and replicator to message id, replication repeat, and replication timeout
              replicationSchedulers: Map[Pair[String, ActorRef], Triple[Long, Cancellable, Cancellable]],
              // map from message id to pair of replication requester and set of replicas
              awaitingReplication: Map[Long, Pair[ActorRef, Set[ActorRef]]]): Receive = {
```

both of which are used through something like:

```
def receive = {
  case JoinedSecondary => {
    receivePartialFunctions = ListMap(secondaryReceiveName -> secondary(0, Map.empty, Map.empty))
    become(receivePartialFunctions)
  }

  case JoinedPrimary => {
    val replicator = context.actorOf(Props(classOf[Replicator], self), s"replicator-${System.nanoTime()}")

    receivePartialFunctions = ListMap(
      primaryReceiveName -> primary(Map(self -> replicator), Map.empty, Map.empty),
      secondaryReceiveName -> secondary(0, Map.empty, Map.empty)
    )
    become(receivePartialFunctions)
  }
}
```

What does this exception mean and what needs to be done to fix it?

Comment: use LoggingReceive for this specific behavior :)

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19827027/how-to-add-logging-function-in-sending-and-receiving-action-in-akka/19838821#19838821

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your echo must not be from type Receive, but

```
PartialFunction[Any,Any]
```

ex:

```
scala> val echo :PartialFunction[Any,Unit] = { case message => println(message) }
echo: PartialFunction[Any,Unit] = <function1>

scala> val echo2 :PartialFunction[Any,Unit] = { case message => println(message+"2") }
echo2: PartialFunction[Any,Unit] = <function1>

scala> (echo andThen echo2)("hi")
hi
()2
```

vs

```
scala> val echo :PartialFunction[Any,Any] = { case message => println(message); message }
echo: PartialFunction[Any,Any] = <function1>


scala> (echo andThen echo2)("hi")
hi
hi2
```

Your first PartialFunction send a result to the second.
Your "echo" service send Unit, so the second can't do anything.