# How to log internal actor state in receive?

Tags: scala, logging, akka

For Actors that can be expressed fairly concisely, it's frustrating to have to add in blocks (`{...}`) just so I can add a log command. I would like to log my internal state before the message is handled and then after the message is handled - is this possible?

```
def receive = {
    // I want to log here instead and remove the non-critical logs from below
    //  e.g. log.debug(s"Received $message")
    //       log.debug(s"Internal state is $subscriptions")
    case RegisterChannel(name, owner) => {
      getChannel(name) match {
        case Some(deadChannel: DeadChannel) => {
          subscriptions += (RealChannel(name, Server(owner)) -> subscriptions(deadChannel))
          subscriptions -= deadChannel
          context.watch(owner)
          log.debug(s"Replaced $deadChannel with a real channel $channels")
        }
        case Some(realChannel: RealChannel) =>
          log.error(s"Refusing to use RegisterChannel($name, $owner) due to $realChannel")
        case None => {
          subscriptions += (RealChannel(name, Server(owner)) -> Vector())
          context.watch(owner)
          log.debug(s"Registered a new channel $channels")
        }
      }
    }

    case Terminated(dead) => {
      getRole(dead) match {
        case Some(client: Client) => // Remove subscriptions
          log.debug(s"Received Client Terminated($dead) $client")
          subscriptionsFor(client).foreach { subscription =>
            subscriptions += (subscription._1 -> subscription._2.filterNot(c => c == client))
          }
        case Some(server: Server) => { // Remove any channels
          log.debug(s"Received Server Terminated($dead) $server")
          channelsBy(server).foreach { realChannel =>
            subscriptions += (DeadChannel(realChannel.name) -> subscriptions(realChannel))
            subscriptions -= realChannel
          }
        }
        case None =>
          log.debug(s"Received Terminated($dead) but no channel is registered")
      }
    }
    // I want to log here as well, to see what effect the message had
    //  e.g. log.debug(s"Finished $message")
    //       log.debug(s"Internal state is now $subscriptions")
}
```

I'm not sure if this is an Akka-specific or Scala pattern-matching specific question, so I tagged both

EDIT: After trying @aepurniet 's answer, I have no idea how to solve the compiler error. receive needs to return `PartialFunction[Any,Unit]`, but when match is not the only item in the `=> {...}` it seems to be returning `Any=>AnyRef`

```
// Compiler error because msg=>{...} is not proper type
def receive = msg => { 
    log.info(s"some log")

    msg match {
      case RegisterChannel(name, owner) => {
        getChannel(name) match {
    <snip>
```

Answer (score 5):

`received = { case ... }` is actually shorthand for `received = msg => msg match { case ... }`. you can rewrite that `receive = msg => { log.info(..); msg match { case ... } }` you may have to additionally specify types.

Comment: This looks so close. When I tried it I got the type problem you predicted, but I can't figure out how to resolve that. I've edited the post with this final little issue, would really appreciate if you'd take a second look

Answer (score 3):

There is [akka.event.LoggingReceive](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/#akka.event.LoggingReceive) that you can use like this:

```
def receive = LoggingReceive {
  case ...
}
```

Then you set `akka.actor.debug.receive` to `on` and this will log (to DEBUG) all message that were received and whether they were handled or not.

See [Tracing Actor Invocations](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/testing.html#Tracing_Actor_Invocations) section in the official documentation of Akka.

For the additional state logging, you can do something similar to `LoggingReceive`

```
def withStateLogging(handler: Receive): Receive = {
  case msg if handler.isDefinedAt(msg) ⇒
    log.debug("before actual receive")
    log.debug(s"received: $msg")
    log.debug(s"state: $state")
    handler(msg)
    log.debug("after actual receive")
    log.debug(s"finished: $msg")
    log.debug(s"state: $state")
}

def receive = withStateLogging {
  case ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Compiler complains because Actor#receive return type is Receive which is actually defined as

```
type Receive = PartialFunction[Any, Unit]
```

Here is nice example how your problem can be solved with stackable traits: [how to add logging function in sending and receiving action in akka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19827027/how-to-add-logging-function-in-sending-and-receiving-action-in-akka)

It is a little tricky and overrides default behavior of [PartialFunction](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.PartialFunction).